# Change Class of a specific div onClick, among many div's with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the class of only the div whose button is clicked. I tried something like this but it is not available

```
$(".a",this).toggleClass( "b" ); //
```

What would be an alternate way to do this?

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".a").toggleClass("b");
});
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <button class="button">clickme</button>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <button class="button">clickme</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wrong selector**. You selector is looking for element with class `a` in clicked button. which return nothing.

You need to traverse to parent:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass( "b" );
});
```

Comment: now if i have something like this and i want same behavior as div
http://jsfiddle.net/qg9hv5g7/ @Milind

Comment: @shubhamsharma: i did not get you. it does the job right??

Comment: as i cllick on the other button h1's toggle at that time also @Milind

Comment: it isn't working but zaki answered this Thankyou for helping @Milind

Answer (score 2):

use `parent()`

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("b");
});
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <button class="button">clickme</button>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <button class="button">clickme</button>
</div>
```

Comment: now if i have something like this and i want same behaviour as div
http://jsfiddle.net/qg9hv5g7/

Comment: Thankyou yes i want this only